# make the sidebars and the "content" region the same length as each-other?

Tags: 7, theming

I have a website that has regions that are uneven. the sidebar first is a different length than the content, and the content is a different length that sidebar second. it looks something like this:
[image]

I could fix it manually in the css and make them the same length, but then any time I add something to any of them, it becomes uneven again. is there any way (or any module) to fix it so that it will dynamically stay the same length, so that when I add something to the content, and it becomes longer that the sidebars, they will fill with white-space and become the same length as the longest content?

Comment: This is a general HTML/CSS question and is not specific to Drupal

Comment: I'm wondering if there is a module that could do it for me, that's why i'm asking it on drupal answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using Faux Columns. it basically repeats a blank image so that the columns will match the length of the longest element. this creates the illusion of equal lengths, hence the name "faux" or "fake"

Answer (score 3):

There is the [Equal Heights jQuery](http://drupal.org/project/equalheights) module.

> This modules implements a [jQuery Equal Heights plugin](http://www.cssnewbie.com/equalheights-jquery-plugin/) that can equalize the height of the elements of the specified class.

Comment: I installed it and I got a: "Notice: Undefined variable: js in equalheights_init() (line 55 of /home/tennis/public_html/sites/all/modules/equalheights/equalheights.module)."  error

Comment: Sorry. I have never used the module (only was aware of it's existence). There appears to be an issue in the module's queue directly specifying this error. http://drupal.org/node/1012032

Answer (score 3):

This is not Drupal specific problem.
Try one of suggestions reported on [Equal Height Columns using CSS](http://www.ejeliot.com/blog/61): It has two CSS solutions, and one JavaScript solution.